# Removing characters using RegExp Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to remove characters using regular expressions in Perl. After showing `:set list` on vim, the characters, with formatting are shown below:

```
R$
$
e$
a$
$
di$
n$
U$
```

This substitution works, but it is too broad for my purposes:

```
$text =~ s/\w{1,2}//g;
```

The substitution I would like to make is:

```
$text =~ s/\w{1,2}$//g;
```

However, that does not remove any of the below characters. I am confused as to why this is. I'm wondering whether this has to do with possible Unicode characters; if so, how do I see and remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to use the `m` modifier to treat the regex as multiple lines. [Here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) is the documentation.

```
$text =~ s/\w{1,2}$//mg;
```

---

Here is an example that I copied and pasted from vim with `:set list`

```
#!/bin/perl$
use strict;$
use warnings;$
$
my $text = <<EOD;$
R$
$
e$
a$
$
di$
n$
U$
EOD$
$
$text =~ s/\w{1,2}$//gm;$
$
print $text;$
```

The output is a bunch of blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

`$` is an anchor character in regex which means end of string or line(similar to `\Z`). You need to escape the `$` with `\`

```
$text =~ s/\w{1,2}\$//g;
```

In your input I have seen you are also removing only `$` character. In that case you have to make the `\w{0,2}`, means any alphanumeric with underscore(`_`) having 0 to 2 in lengths.

Comment: `$` is not the actual `$` character. It is a construct of `:set list` on vim, which shows formatting.